# Is there a way of returning the date in one line?

Tags: javascript

As a beginner I am trying to understand if there is a way to convert this into a one-liner? Have tried to search of course before asking. I need an output in Selenium that outputs HHMM without : . So, I need to know if there's a way to put this into oneline?

```
const now = new Date();
console.log(now.getHours() + "" + now.getMinutes());
```

Thanks a lot for helping out!

Comment: I don't think you could achieve something line that. While you need to access the same object twice, there's no chance to rewrite this snippet of code in one-liner format.

Comment: As whitespace is more or less irrelevant in javascript, you could basically write every piece of code in *one line*.  So what's the real question here? Aesthetics? Or something more sophisticated? If so, please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an option

```js
console.log(new Date().toTimeString().split(':').slice(0,2).join(' '))
```